# Constraint on Ability to Switch Input Values for Trajectory Optimization in Model Predictive Control Framework

Tags: optimization, input, constraints, drake

I am trying to add a constraint which specifies that, in the optimization, the solver must pick a value of u for a set duration of time and can only switch after that set amount of time. For instance, say I have a mechanical device which can only switch its input value every 10 seconds. Then, I want the optimizer to account for that. I'll just attach the code here:

```
        for it_i in range(0, N-1, equivalence_samples):

            print("N: {}".format(N))

            for it_j in range(0, equivalence_samples - 1):

                if (it_i + it_j + 1) > N-1:
                    print("Breaking")
                    break
                else:
                    constraint_u0 = prog.AddConstraint(u[0, it_i + it_j] == u[0, it_i + it_j + 1]) # add equivalence constraints
                    constraint_u1 = prog.AddConstraint(u[1, it_i + it_j] == u[1, it_i + it_j + 1]) # add equivalence constraints
                    print('Constraint_u_PE: {}'.format(constraint_u0))
                    print('Constraint_u_NI: {}'.format(constraint_u1))
```

I have implemented this in, what I expect to be a working solution. Sometimes it seems like it is working and other times, it does not.

I will show some photos of the output constraints from this and then a not working example.

[image: example constraints part 1]

[image: example constraints part 2]

Then, here are the plots that come out which clearly show there is some delineation between the switching times, but the values are not equivalent. I am attaching the code which generates this plot as well.

[image: almost equal inputs!!]

```
        u_sol = result.GetSolution(u)
        u_time = np.linspace(0, N-1, num = N)
        # u_sol_trajectory = PiecewisePolynomial.ZeroOrderHold(u_time, u_sol)

        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(u_time, u_sol[0, :], 'o')
        plt.plot(u_time, u_sol[1, :], 'o')
        plt.xlabel('time steps')
        plt.ylabel('u [mcg/min]')
        plt.legend(['u_PE', 'u_NI'])
```

Comment: From the plot u_PE satisfies your constraint, but u_NI does not? Could you check if your problem is solved successfully? You could call `print(result.is_success())` to check whether the optimization problem is solved or not.

Comment: Yes, I have checked and each time it prints that it is solved successfully each time. Even when a plot like the above is output.

Comment: A question that might be helpful is is there a value below which that the program recognizes to be zero? I even look at the solutions that look like they are solving it correctly, and the difference between two inputs that are supposed to be the same is not 0.

Comment: The accuracy depends on the solver. Normally the accuracy should be about 1E-6. You could get the solver by `print(result.get_solver_id().name())`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! That is precisely the issue. It seems that my constraints are not explicit enough to produce the results I am looking for given the solvers accuracy. Thank you! This is helpful! Should I write out the points that helped me figure out what was happening?

Comment: Yes, it would be great if you could write out the points that helped you figure out the issue, it could help future users. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The particular solver that was being used in this case is the OSQP solver. Although I, in an ideal solver world, specified the correct constraints in the above code (that input 1 == input 2, input 2 == input 3, etc.), I did not account for the fact that solvers have an accuracy with which they try to uphold the constraints.

I can fix this problem by either updating the accuracy of the solver (as recommended by https://osqp.discourse.group/t/constraints-violated/143) or inputing more explicit constraints. I solved this with the second option. Now, I am specifying not just constraints like the following pattern:

input 1 == input 2, input 2 == input 3, etc.

but I am also including constraints like the following pattern:

input 1 == input 3, input 1 == input 4, input 1 == input 5

input 2 == input 4, input 2 == input 5 etc.

By being more explicit, my solver is now doing what I asked with small deviations from the constraint. The small deviations are acceptable for my application, however! It is a bit slower, but this isn't a problem for what I am using this for at the moment. Here is my updated code:

```
        for it_i in range(0, N-1, equivalence_samples):
            
            for it_j in range(0, equivalence_samples - 1):

                for it_f in range(1, equivalence_samples - it_j):

                    if (it_i + it_j + it_f) > N-1:
                        print("Breaking")
                        break
                    else:
                        con_0 = eq(u[:, it_i + it_j], u[:, it_i + it_j + it_f])
                        constraint_u = prog.AddConstraint(con_0) # add equivalence constraints
                        print('Constraint_u: {}'.format(constraint_u))
```

Not the prettiest code in the world, but it works.

Comment: I am wondering what would happen if you impose the equality constraint in a loop like
input1 == input2, input2 == input3, ..., inputN = input1
So previously you had N-1 equality constraint, now just add one more equality constraint between the last and the first inputs.